# How to prove that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$, $n+\lfloor \sqrt{n} +\frac12 \rfloor$ cannot be a complete square?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is my thinking process:

Let $k=4n$, so $n=\frac{k}{4}$, then $k\in \Bbb{N}$. Then the expression becomes $\frac{k}{4}+\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{k} +\frac12 \rfloor$. But then I don't know how to continue. Could someone give some insight?

Comment: Hmm, but why do you let $k=4n$? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I think the standard way to show this is to let $n$ and $k$ be integers such that $$k\leq n+ \sqrt n+1/2 <k+1$$and show that $k$ can never be a perfect square.

Answer (score 5):

First, this floor and square roots are ugly, let's rewrite the relationship between $n$ and $\lfloor \sqrt n + \frac 12 \rfloor$ properly :

Let $k,n$ be positive integers.

$k = \lfloor \sqrt n + \frac 12 \rfloor \\
\iff k \le \sqrt n + \frac 12 < k+1 \\
\iff k-\frac 12 \le \sqrt n < k + \frac 12 \\
\iff k^2-k+\frac 14 \le n < k^2+k+\frac 14 \\
\iff k^2-k+1 \le n \le k^2+k$

This is much better. But we are actually interested in $n+k$, so we can continue and get

$\iff k^2+1 \le n+k \le k^2+2k \\
\iff k^2 < n+k < k^2+2k+1 \\
\iff k^2 < n+k < (k+1)^2$

So if $k= \lfloor \sqrt n + \frac 12 \rfloor$, then $k^2 < n+k < (k+1)^2$ : $n+k$ cannot be a square, because if it was its square root would be an integer between $k$ and $k+1$ and there is no such thing.